# Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium

i was trying to find a xpath but i can't find it  i try css selector, class name etc... but still doesnt work (ps: i am new programming on python)

error:  `Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="knowledge-currency__updatable-data-column"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]`

my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys('cotação dólar')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
Dolar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="knowledge-currency__updatable-data-column"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]').get_attribute('data-value')

print(Dolar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to separately use the send_keys for `Keys.ENTER`

```
driver.get('http://google.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys('cotação dólar',Keys.ENTER)

Dolar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="knowledge-currency__updatable-data-column"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]').get_attribute('data-value')

print(Dolar)
```

**O/P**

74.21700000000001

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a bit tweak :

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
input_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
input_box.send_keys('cotação dólar'+Keys.ENTER)
Dolar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="knowledge-currency__updatable-data-column"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]').get_attribute('data-value')

print(Dolar)
```

Also you are using absolute xpath, I would advise you to change that to relative xpath or there are other reliable locators available.

like this :-

```
input_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
```